# React onClick update useState variable and render updated

Tags: reactjs

I know this question has been asked before, but the solutions were different from the way I structure/code my React app as shown below. How use one update/render based on the updated `listData`?

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

const PageName = () => {

  const [listData, setlistData] = useState([]);

  function add(){
    let newrow = {};
    listData.push(newrow);
    setlistData(listData);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {listData.length}

      <button onClick={() => add()}>Add</button>

      {
        listData.map(function (row, i) {
          return (
            <p key={i}>row</p>
          );
        })
      }
    </div>
  );
};

export default PageName;
```

Comment: I can't totally tell what your question is.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking... But `listData.push(newrow);` mutates state, so you should fix that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a state variable it is react's job to rerender. Your job is to ensure you are passing in a new reference to `setState()` without mutating the state.

Use `...` spread operator.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const PageName = () => {

  const [listData, setlistData] = useState([]);

  function add(){
    let newrow = {};
    let newListData = [...listData];
     newListData.push(newrow);
    setlistData(newListData);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {listData.length}

      <button onClick={() => add()}>Add</button>

      {
        listData.map(function (row, i) {
          return (
            <p key={i}>row</p>
          );
        })
      }
    </div>
  );
};

export default PageName;
```

Comment: thank you sir! learnt something here

Answer (score 1):

The reference stays the same if you only push to the same object .
If you push to the list , under the hood the list gets the data but React cannot rerender because the object `listData` does not save value but reference , which doesn't change . Creating a new object by copying all the data and putting it in a new object changes the reference of  `newreferenceListData` ,which causes re render.

```
 function add(){
    let newrow = {};
    let newreferenceListData = [...listData,newrow];
    setlistData(newreferenceListData);
  }
```